# Cart total is displaying NaN instead of total price

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, e-commerce

So the problem I am currently facing is this. I have a Cart logic located in the CartContext. Everything works except the total number of prices it is displaying NAN. Here is the link to the CodeSandbox for a better understanding https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sound-5y7pg?file=/src/CartItem.js:1486-1494

```
import React from "react";


function getCartFromLocalStorage() {
  return localStorage.getItem("cart")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
    : [];
}

const CartContext = React.createContext();

function CartProvider({ children }) {
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState(getCartFromLocalStorage());
  const [total, setTotal] = React.useState(0);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));

    let newTotal = cart.reduce((total, cartItem) => {
      return (total += cartItem.amount * cartItem.price);
    }, 0);
    newTotal = parseFloat(newTotal.toFixed(2));
    setTotal(newTotal);
    // cart items
    let newCartItems = cart.reduce((total, cartItem) => {
      return (total += cartItem.amount);
    }, 0);
    setCartItems(newCartItems);
  }, [cart]);

  // global functions
  const removeItem = id => {
    setCart([...cart].filter(item => item.id !== id));
  };
  const increaseAmount = id => {
    const newCart = [...cart].map(item => {
      return item.id === id
        ? { ...item, amount: item.amount + 1 }
        : { ...item };
    });
    setCart(newCart);
  };
  const decreaseAmount = (id, amount) => {
    if (amount === 1) {
      removeItem(id);
      return;
    } else {
      const newCart = [...cart].map(item => {
        return item.id === id
          ? { ...item, amount: item.amount - 1 }
          : { ...item };
      });

      setCart(newCart);
    }
  };
  const addToCart = book => {
    const { id, image, by, bookName,RegularPrice } = book;
    const item = [...cart].find(item => item.id === id);

    if (item) {
      increaseAmount(id);
      return;
    } else {
      const newItem = { id, image, by, bookName, RegularPrice, amount: 1 };
      const newCart = [...cart, newItem];
      setCart(newCart);
    }
  };
  const clearCart = () => {
    setCart([]);
  };
  return (
    <CartContext.Provider
      value={{
        cart,
        cartItems,
        total,
        removeItem,
        increaseAmount,
        decreaseAmount,
        addToCart,
        clearCart
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { CartContext, CartProvider };
```

Comment: Are you sure that that cartItem is a number?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem - I am getting the actual value. But what I noticed is the first item from each type doesn't affect the total value but instead inserting a 0 quantity and 0 total.

Comment: You are getting the total price of the items?

Answer (score 0):

Your CodeSandbox link works fine for me. Total is not shown as NaN. The only problem: change the initial amount from 0 to 1 (*CartContext.js, line 48*):

```
cart.concat({
  amount: 1,
  /* ... */
})
```

Comment: How are you getting the total price, when in mine sandbox is displaying NaN

Comment: Yes I do. Checkout yourself (just add 2 items instead of 1, because of the problem I mentioned). What browser/version do you use?

Comment: could you link that sandbox

Comment: The link above from your question :) https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sound-5y7pg
Probably the problem is a different browser? Mine: Google Chrome 89.0.4389.114

Comment: did you add cart.concat

Comment: bcs its still the same

Comment: OK look. I'm just saying that for me it works fine and I cannot reproduce the problem (and according to comments, other people can't either). If you still have it then go on and share with us some additional info. I'm glad to help but honestly, I don't want to spend time debugging your code.

Comment: It is strange it doesnt even work i the sandbox