# Total is displaying NaN in Cart

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, commerce

So the problem I am currently facing is this. I have a Cart logic located in the CartContext. Everything works except the total located in Checkout Component, it should sum all the prices of the items in the cart, but instead is displaying NAN. Here is the link to the CodeSandbox for a better understanding https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sound-5y7pg?file=/src/CartItem.js:1486-1494.Please comment if something is wrong with sandbox

Cart Context

```
import React from "react";
function getCartFromLocalStorage() {
  return localStorage.getItem("cart")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
    : [];
}

const CartContext = React.createContext();

function CartProvider({ children }) {
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState(getCartFromLocalStorage());
  const [total, setTotal] = React.useState(0);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));

    let newTotal = cart.reduce((total, cartItem) => {
      return (total += cartItem.amount * cartItem.price);
    }, 0);
    newTotal = parseFloat(newTotal.toFixed(2));
    setTotal(newTotal);
    // cart items
    let newCartItems = cart.reduce((total, cartItem) => {
      return (total += cartItem.amount);
    }, 0);
    setCartItems(newCartItems);
  }, [cart]);

  // global functions
  const removeItem = id => {
    setCart([...cart].filter(item => item.id !== id));
  };
  const increaseAmount = id => {
    const newCart = [...cart].map(item => {
      return item.id === id
        ? { ...item, amount: item.amount + 1 }
        : { ...item };
    });
    setCart(newCart);
  };
  const decreaseAmount = (id, amount) => {
    if (amount === 1) {
      removeItem(id);
      return;
    } else {
      const newCart = [...cart].map(item => {
        return item.id === id
          ? { ...item, amount: item.amount - 1 }
          : { ...item };
      });

      setCart(newCart);
    }
  };
  const addToCart = book => {
    const { id, image, by, bookName,RegularPrice } = book;
    const item = [...cart].find(item => item.id === id);

    if (item) {
      increaseAmount(id);
      return;
    } else {
      const newItem = { id, image, by, bookName, RegularPrice, amount: 1 };
      const newCart = [...cart, newItem];
      setCart(newCart);
    }
  };
  const clearCart = () => {
    setCart([]);
  };
  return (
    <CartContext.Provider
      value={{
        cart,
        cartItems,
        total,
        removeItem,
        increaseAmount,
        decreaseAmount,
        addToCart,
        clearCart
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { CartContext, CartProvider };
```

Cart Item

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import {Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { CartContext } from "../../context/cart";
import { FaAngleDown, FaAngleUp } from "react-icons/fa";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";
export default function CartItem({ id, image,bookName, RegularPrice, by, amount }) {
  const { removeItem, increaseAmount, decreaseAmount } = React.useContext(
    CartContext
  );
  return (
      <div id={id} className="cart__item">
          <img className='cart__image' src={image}  />
        <div className='cart__itemdesc'>
         <h4>{bookName}</h4>
        <h6 className='cart__by'>By: {by}</h6>
        <button
          className="cart__removebtn"
          onClick={() => {
            removeItem(id);
          }}
         >
          Remove
        </button>
        <div>
        <button
          className="cart-btn amount-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            increaseAmount(id);
          }}
        >
          <FaAngleUp />
        </button>
        <p className="item-amount">{amount}</p>
        <button
          className="cart-btn amount-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            decreaseAmount(id, amount);
          }}
        >
          <FaAngleDown />
        </button>
      </div>
        </div>  
        <span className='circle'><span className='circleone'></span></span>
        <span className='cart__regular'>{RegularPrice}</span>      
        <div>   
        <Checkout />
        </div>    
    </div>
  );
}
```

Checkout

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react'
import { CartContext } from '../../context/cart'
import {Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import EmptyCart from './EmptyCart';

const Checkout = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  const {cart, total} = useContext(CartContext)
  if (cart.length === 0) {
    return <EmptyCart />;
  }

    return (
        <div className='checkout'>
            <h2>Summary</h2>
            <h2>Subtotal : ${total}</h2>
            <Link to='/stripecontainer' className='checkout__btnOne'>Proceed to Checkout</Link>            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Checkout
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cart total is showing NAN instead of Total price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66960380/cart-total-is-showing-nan-instead-of-total-price)

Comment: Seem to work in the sandbox?

Comment: Please don't continue to post the same question [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66960380/cart-total-is-showing-nan-instead-of-total-price) and [over](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66954600/215552) again. If you have new information, edit the original question.

Comment: I dont know how does it work in your sandbox, when in mine is displaying NaN

Comment: My sandbox is working, but i have to click twice on an item to be counted as amount 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with bad data. The proper response in this case is to request sanitized data from whoever is in charge of the backend. If the person in charge of the backend is still you, you should fix this in backend, not in frontend.

Long story short, don't use `parseFloat()`. When you have to cast strings to numbers, a safer bet is using `Number(val)` (or its shorthand: `+val`). (it's still a bet, though...)

Another minor thing: you're adding items to cart with `amount: 0`. Shouldn't it be `1`?

```
setCart(
  cart.concat({
    amount: 1,
    price: +book.RegularPrice,
    ...book
  })
);
```

And one last note: what you have now will override your assignments to `amount` and `price` if `book` already has any of those properties set. If you want to have complete control (and confidence) over the assignment, you should spread the object first, then assign:

```
setCart(
  cart.concat({
    ...book,
    amount: 1,
    price: +book.RegularPrice
  })
);
```

See it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-germain-8ypd9?file=/src/CartContext.js).